# Yii2 Unable to convert html to pdf

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, yii2-advanced-app, mpdf

I am trying to convert an `HTML` page into pdf using [mpdf](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf).

```
 public function actionIndex()
{

   

    $type = "";
    $dataProvider = "";
    $columns = "";
    if(isset($_POST['cust_id']))
    {
        $type = "bill";

        $content = $this->renderPartial('_bill', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);

        $pdf = new Pdf([
            // set to use core fonts only
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            // A4 papr format
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            // portrait orientation
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            // stream to browser inline
            'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            // your html content input
            'content' => $content,
            // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
            // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
            //'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            //'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:14px}',
            // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Bill'],
            // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => ['Generated On: ' . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")],
                'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}']
            ]
        ]);

        $pdf->filename = "Bill.pdf";
      
        try {
            return $pdf->render();
        } catch (MpdfException $e) {
        } catch (CrossReferenceException $e) {
        } catch (PdfTypeException $e) {
        } catch (PdfParserException $e) {
        } catch (InvalidConfigException $e) {
        }

    }

    try {
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'type' => $type
            /*'searchModel' => $searchModel*/
        ]);
    } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
    }
}
```

**HTML Page**

```
<?PHP

 /* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

 $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
 ?>
 <!doctype HTML>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!--Css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

 <title>Electricity Bill</title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <!--Main body-->
 <div class="container">

 <!--Header-->
 <section class="row" style="border-bottom: tomato 2px solid; padding: 25px;">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="size">
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 text">
        <h5>Company</h5>
        <h6>Web Site</h6>
        <h6>Telephones:</h6>
        <h6><u>Bill for electricity, Water and Allied Charges</u></h6>
    </div>
</section>
<!--Ends-->

<!--Table Upper-->
<section class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">

    <!--Left Side-->
    <div class="col-3 ">
        <table class="table table-hover table-borderless ">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Consumer no</td>
                <td>12345789</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>Model Town</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Consumer Name</td>
                <td>Faisal</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meter No</td>
                <td>43748</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meter Type</td>
                <td>1/Phase</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Previous Reading</td>
                <td>178923</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Current Reading</td>
                <td>180199</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Difference</td>
                <td>1275</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Average Units</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Units</td>
                <td>1275</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--Ends-->

    <!--Right Side-->
    <div class="col-9">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col ">Billing Month</th>
                <th scope="col ">M.R Date</th>
                <th scope="col ">Issue Date</th>
                <th scope="col ">Due Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>4 - 2020</td>
                <td>27-APRIL-2020</td>
                <td>05-MAY-2020</td>
                <td>12-MAY-2020</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>


        <!--Second Table-->
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="col-3">
                <table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" style="font-size: 16px;">Tariff</th>
                        <th scope="col">Member</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Units</th>
                        <th scope="col">UnitRates</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1-100</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1-100</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>101-300</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>101-300</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>301-700</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>301-700</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>above</td>
                        <td>21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>above</td>
                        <td>21</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>


            <!--Bill History-->
            <div class="col-9 ">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <h4>Bill History</h4>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Month/Year</th>
                        <th scope="col">Units</th>
                        <th scope="col">Bill Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Payment</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                <table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3/2020</td>
                        <td>1,188</td>
                        <td>35,378</td>
                        <td>35,378</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2/2020</td>
                        <td>1,405</td>
                        <td>35,378</td>
                        <td>35,378</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1/2020</td>
                        <td>2,395</td>
                        <td>67,893</td>
                        <td>67,893</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12/2019</td>
                        <td>3/2020</td>
                        <td>3/2020</td>
                        <td>3/2020</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>11/2019</td>
                        <td>877</td>
                        <td>33,034</td>
                        <td>33,034</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>10/2019</td>
                        <td>1,507</td>
                        <td>43,348</td>
                        <td>43,348</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>9/2019</td>
                        <td>1,812</td>
                        <td>51,798</td>
                        <td>51,798</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8/2019</td>
                        <td>2,246</td>
                        <td>57,052</td>
                        <td>57,052</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7/2019</td>
                        <td>2700</td>
                        <td>69,044</td>
                        <td>69,044</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6/2019</td>
                        <td>2,383</td>
                        <td>60,375</td>
                        <td>60,375</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5/2019</td>
                        <td>2,372</td>
                        <td>61,485</td>
                        <td>61,485</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4/2019</td>
                        <td>1,728</td>
                        <td>48,804</td>
                        <td>48,804</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3/2019</td>
                        <td>1,405</td>
                        <td>28,598</td>
                        <td>28,598</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End-->


    </div>


    <!--Horizontal Table 1-->
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col ">Energy Charge</th>
            <th scope="col ">E-Arrears</th>
            <th scope="col ">I-Tax</th>
            <th scope="col ">GST</th>
            <th scope="col ">E-Tax</th>
            <th scope="col ">F-Tax</th>
            <th scope="col ">R.G.S.T</th>
            <th scope="col ">Total Amount</th>
            <th scope="col ">Amt W Due date</th>
            <th scope="col ">Amt A Due date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>26,096</td>
            <td>3,433</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5,020</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>34,549</td>
            <td>34,549</td>
            <td>34,845</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--End-->

    <!--Horizontal Table 2-->
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col ">C-Duty</th>
            <th scope="col ">Rd Maint</th>
            <th scope="col ">Mosque</th>
            <th scope="col ">Conserve</th>
            <th scope="col ">Sewerage</th>
            <th scope="col ">Misc</th>
            <th scope="col ">Sanitation</th>
            <th scope="col ">Tv fee</th>
            <th scope="col ">Rent</th>
            <th scope="col ">Rent Arrear</th>
            <th scope="col ">Amt W Due date</th>
            <th scope="col ">Amt A Due date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>650</td>
            <td>925</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>24,15</td>
            <td>24,15</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--end-->


    <!--Horizontal Table 3-->
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col ">F/MRC</th>
            <th scope="col ">F/MRC Arrears</th>
            <th scope="col ">Water Charges</th>
            <th scope="col ">Water Arrears</th>
            <th scope="col ">Total Amount</th>
            <th scope="col ">Amt W.Due Date</th>
            <th scope="col ">Amt A.Due Date</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1,060</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1,060</td>
            <td>1,060</td>
            <td>1,070</td>

        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--end-->

    <!--Horizontal Table 4-->
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Grand Total</td>
            <td>38,024</td>
            <td>39,339</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--end-->

</section>


<!--Second Table-->
<!-- <section>
    <div class="row ">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="" class="size-default">

    </div>
</section>-->

<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-2 cl">
            <img src=" logo.jpg " alt=" logo " class=" size ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 text padding">
            <h5>Company.</h5>
            <h6><u>Bill for electricity, Water and Allied Charges</u></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="row">

    <!--Horizontal Table 1-->
    <table class=" table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope=" col ">Energy Charge</th>
            <th scope=" col ">E-Arrears</th>
            <th scope=" col ">I-Tax</th>
            <th scope=" col ">GST</th>
            <th scope=" col ">E-Tax</th>
            <th scope=" col ">F-Tax</th>
            <th scope=" col ">R.G.S.T</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Total Amount</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Amt W Due date</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Amt A Due date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>26,096</td>
            <td>3,433</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5,020</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>34,549</td>
            <td>34,549</td>
            <td>34,845</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--End-->

    <!--Horizontal Table 2-->
    <table class=" table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope=" col ">C-Duty</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Rd Maint</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Mosque</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Conserve</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Sewerage</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Misc</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Sanitation</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Tv fee</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Rent</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Rent Arrear</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Amt W Due date</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Amt A Due date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>650</td>
            <td>925</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>24,15</td>
            <td>24,15</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--end-->


    <!--Horizontal Table 3-->
    <table class=" table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope=" col ">F/MRC</th>
            <th scope=" col ">F/MRC Arrears</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Water Charges</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Water Arrears</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Total Amount</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Amt W.Due Date</th>
            <th scope=" col ">Amt A.Due Date</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1,060</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1,060</td>
            <td>1,060</td>
            <td>1,070</td>

        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--end-->

    <!--Horizontal Table 4-->
    <table class=" table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Consumer No</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Billing Month</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Grand Total</td>
            <td>38,024</td>
            <td>39,339</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--end-->
</section>
```

Ther error I am getting is `Undefined offset: -1` at  `if ($this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['s'] > 0 && !$this->mpdf->nestedtablejustfinished)`

```
    /* -- TABLES -- */
    if ($this->mpdf->tableLevel) {
        // If already something on the line
        if ($this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['s'] > 0 && !$this->mpdf->nestedtablejustfinished) {
            $this->mpdf->_saveCellTextBuffer("\n");
            if (!isset($this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['maxs'])) {
                $this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['maxs'] = $this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['s'];
            } elseif ($this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['maxs'] < $this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['s']) {
                $this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['maxs'] = $this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['s'];
            }
            $this->mpdf->cell[$this->mpdf->row][$this->mpdf->col]['s'] = 0; // reset
        }
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7oLfuvx/)

Comment: what version of mpdf are you using ?

Comment: using `"kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "dev-master",`

Comment: also, I have installed `mpdf` version `8.0.6`

Comment: did you share your HTML code in its entirety? It is possible you have a markup error that is causing this. Anyway, this notice should not happen, so please fill an issue at mPDF github repository (according to an issue template).